# ZSH show completions without pressing tab like vim's ctrlp?`

Tags: zsh

Is it possible to update zsh's completion list with each key typed for commands that take a file/folder as a parameter (e.g. cd). In other words for these kinds of commands, the tab key would be implicitly pressed after each keypress:

cd ~/
(directories in ~/ are shown in the completion lsit)

(directories in ~/ are shown that start with a).

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was very curious after reading this question, so I started to research to see if it was possible. After some digging I arrived at `auto-fu`: https://github.com/hchbaw/auto-fu.zsh

`auto-fu` works quite well in my (very) brief testing. Hopefully it is what you're after.

Comment: Wow thanks this is great! A little bit buggy, but exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Felix: Just for reference, there was a discussion on the zsh-workers list a month ago, resulting in a (improved?) function, which is based on `auto-fu`: Initial post: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00182.html, last release: http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2013/msg00194.html

Comment: Too bad there isn't a way to disable the completion behavior for certain commands (auto-fu says it has this feature but it does not work). I use fasd/autojump (j "part of file path) to navigate between directories, and fasd/autojump become unusable with these autocompletion systems because of the completion style for fasd/autojump.

Comment: After some time trying both solutions out I stopped using them, they both have severe problems that make them unusable (terminals hang when typing long strings for example).